# Как без исключения проверить наличие ресурса?

Tags: .net, c#

Есть у меня вот такой код

```
  new ResourceManager(base_name, this.TargetType.Assembly).GetString(base.DisplayNameValue);
```

взятый в try-catch. Вероятность того, что ресурса не будет, и потребуется альтернативный способ получения результата, велика. Когда много обращений к несуществующим ресурсам, программа тормозит.

Как проверить наличие ресурса до того, как попытаться его получить?

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку, если ресурса нет, то он вряд ли появится в дальнейшем, можно запоминать в HashMap ресурсы, обращения по которым дали ошибку и при последующих обращениях к ним сразу использовать альтернативные способы. Этот способ поможет, если идет частое повторное обращение к одним и тем же ресурсам. Можно использовать этот метод по другому, например, при запуске программы сразу собирать список имеющихся ресурсов и потом плясать от него.

Comment: Не, не тот случай. Частого повторного нет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать получить список всех строк ресурсов в сборке с помощью Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames и, уже опираясь на него, выбирать существующие.

Comment: base_name в приведённом примере кода оттуда и берётся. Вопрос в том, как детальнее это проверить.